# Task revisions are creating for ECS Fargate service, even i am not changing any task definitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline, aws-fargate

Task revisions are creating for ECS Fargate service, even i am not changing any task definitions.

Used AWS Pipeline for CI/CD. (AWS CodePipeline + ECS Fargate Service)

CI/CD working perfectly, but when new deployment occurs everytime it creates new task defintion.

Comment: for me, it's docker image version changes which lead to new task definition

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to prevent CodePipeline's ECS job worker from creating a new task definition revision every time it is run as this behaviour is by design.